# Load Bootstrap modal on page load without firing button or using jQuery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to launch a Bootstrap modal on page load without firing a HTML button or using jQuery.

Here's my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="my-modal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Hello World!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

This works when you call

```
$('#my-modal').modal('show');
```

But I don't want to call a method or fire a button. Is there a way to launch modal automatically on page load?

#### Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cybercriminal/5gBff/)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Create a CSS class for `.modal` and add `display:block`. Also give `in` class to modal div.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/5gBff/1/)**

CSS

```
.modal {
  display:block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="my-modal" class="modal fade in">
```

**Edit:** Somehow default closing function will not work, you will need to add custom script for that.

Comment: Awesome! It's working. Thank you so much for your quick response and the fix!

Comment: I think you should avoid editing bootstrap.css directly.  Better to use jQuery or create a new class in your own css file.

Comment: this works, but prevents the modal from being closed using `data-dismiss`.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time trying to accommodate this and found that this worked fine for my needs which incorporated a single login page...  Obviously this is not the finished article but an excellent base from which I was able to start with.  Hope it is of some use to someone...

```
<body style="background: #555;">
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="margin-top: 20%;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body…</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

On Bootstrap 5, just create a modal variable with options and runs it with .show()

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('modal'), {keyboard: false, backdrop: 'static'});
myModal.show();
```

Without Jquery, you cannot use this;

```
myModal.modal('show');
```

Comment: actually i was looking something like this but without jquery, because there is no jquery in bottstrap5.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the page onload function

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body onLoad="$('#my-modal').modal('show');">
    <div id="my-modal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Hello World!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The title of the question says "without jquery"!

Answer (score 0):

On Bootstrap 4 --

Add the show class to your modal

```
<div class="modal fade show" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

and following css --

```
.modal {
    display:block;
  }
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the accepted answer from 2013, and has the same problem of the dismiss button now working

Comment: You are probably not including bootstrap's js. That is required to for dismiss functionality to work.

Comment: I am including Bootstrap's JS, but the OPs question was how to do this without using jQuery, which Bootstrap's JS uses

Comment: The dismiss functionality is going to need js I think.

Comment: Yes, but ideally not with jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

On bootstrap 5 and don't use Jquery here my answer;

First we assign an id to the button, select to button and then when page load click automatically this button.

```
document.getElementById("btn-my").click();
```

and in css;

```
#btn-my {
display: none;
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score -3):

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal" data-show role="dialog">
```

*data-show* help you

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question as @TobySpeight says, since in the background JQuery will beused.