# show django-bootstrap modal on any page load

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-bootstrap4

I am trying to use a django-bootstrap4 modal as a nag box to accept a privacy policy.

(I have a custom template filter to check whether this has already been accepted. I am not worried about that bit)

It should open whenever navigating to a new page. I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794363/load-bootstrap-modal-on-page-load-without-firing-button-or-using-jquery), but the modal is not dismissable, not even with a close button. Neither does it shadow the page behind it.

- I have imported the custom css using `<link href="/static/css/auto_modal.css" rel="stylesheet">`, is this correct when using django-bootstrap?
- The code for the modal is in the base.html template. Is it possible to take it into a seperate template just for the modal?

Comment: You should be using `<link href="{% static 'css/auto_modal.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">` to correctly link your static files

Comment: Thanks for that. It didn't solve the problem I was having, but I am glad to know the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to Javascript

make a *my_javascript.js* file in a *static/js/* folder, containing

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#ConfirmGDPRModal").modal('show');
     console.log();
});
```

load it into the base.htmltemplate with

```
<script src="{% static 'js/auto_modal.js' %}"></script>
```

Then create your modal as usual.
I'm still looking into getting this into a seperate html file.